# Reasonable literature on network printing (protocols)

Tags: printing, lpd, ipp

I need some recommendations on reasonable and up-to-date literature about network printing, the corresponding protocols (ipp, lpdp, ...), printjob authentication and accounting in heterogenous networks.

Comment: Chapter 26 (~50 pages) in *Unix and Linux System Administration Handbook*, Nemeth, is about printing. I think it's a great book to read for other reasons too :)

Answer (score 0):

you named a set of old `protocol`. `cups` is new and replaced them. You can combine  `samab` and `cups`.`samab` for sahring `printer`.